# are the urls in grails requestmap (spring security plugin) case insensitive?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have been assigned a bug which probably deals with requestmap table in spring security. I am not allowed to change the requestmap table myself. So, I need to know this:

are the urls in grails requestmap (spring security plugin) case insensitive?

For example: if there is /dashBoard and /dashboard with different roles, does that create a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. Url mapping is case sensitive ad i think spring security mapper is based  on this [AntPathMatcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)